# AlarmManager keeps screen of my device on

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have one problem I need to set AlarmReceiver.

I am using this code for it:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) + 5);
                            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, i, 0);
                            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*5, pIntent);
```

So it means that this AlarmManager will call AlarmReceiver every 5 seconds, but problem is that if I don't turn my screen OFF manually, screen will stay ON and this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

From the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) reference documents:

The parameter `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`, will wake up the device (in case of device sleep) to deliver the Alarm.  You may use `AlarmManager.RTC` but that won't be wake up the device and your Alarm won't be delivered until next time device wakes up.

A better option would be to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for this purpose, as they are designed to carry out the background tasks.